# Chamar Action de Busca no Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc, controller

Tenho Uma Action no Meu controller que Chama um Serviço Que faz uma Busca usando Stored Procedure e me Retorna um Lista.
Fiz o form na View para chamar está Action, só que não está chamando
Segue os Codigos de Cada Processo

Formulario de Busca

```
<p> Buscar Pessoa </p>
<!-- Area de Busca -->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-group">
        <p> Nome </p>
        @Html.TextBox("Nome")
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </div>
}
```

Controller - ActionResult Buscar(string nome)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Buscar(string Nome)
{
    PessoaService srv = new PessoaService();
    srv.Buscar(ID);

    return View("List", srv.Listar());
}
```

buscar Pessoa pela Stored Procedure - no PessoaService

```
public List<Pessoa> Buscar(string nome)
{
    using(var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var Result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Pessoa>("SP_Busca_Cliente").ToList();
        return Result.ToList();
    }
}
```

PERGUNTA
   ---- Como faço para chamar está Action e Retornar a Pessoa Buscada

Comment: Olhando muito por cima, acredito que falta você especificar que o method http disparado pelo form deve ser POST, afinal sua action só ira responder a requisições POST. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Cara, Consegui Chamar, Usando deste jeito ai, Agora só preciso criar as Variaveis do tipo SqlParameter para passar como parametro pro meu Stored Procedure, Voçe tem alguma ideia mais facil de passar?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso que você deseja? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters